# How to create a composed test fragment

Tags: rest, jmeter

Let's suppose that to make a REST request C, I need to make a request A and a request B as a set up for the business case.

I know how to run 3 requests sequentially in jmeter, but I want just to C be measured by jmeter stats to see tps and response time. Is there a way to do that?

Let's say that A and B not necessarily will be executed in a near time in a real case, but they need to be requested before C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as children of requests A and B and use the following code:

   ```
   prev.setIgnore()
   ```

   [image]

   this line will invoke [SampleResult.setIgnore()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) function suppressing the output of the sampler(s) in the JSR223 PostProcessor's [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules). Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more information on [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shortcuts available for [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).

   [image]
2. Another option is using [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) which allows removing "not interesting" entries from the .jtl results file. Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) (you will need [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) as well), example command line would be something like:

   ```
   FilterResults.bat --output-file onlyrequestc.jtl --input-file result.jtl --include-labels "Request C"
   ```

   [image]